# Pandas_Merge two large Datasets

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am using Pandas for my analysis (I am currently using Jupyter Network). I have a two large datasets (one is 14 GB and the second one is 4 GB). I need to merge this two datasets based on a column. I employ the following code:

```
 df = pd.merge(aa, bb, on='column', how='outer')
```

Normally, this code works. However, since my datasets are large, it take to much time. I run my code 4 hours ago and it still continuing. The RAM of my machine is 8 GB. 
Do you have any suggestions for that?

Comment: Could you show some description of the databases you're dealing with? Have you considered working with a subset of the original data? [This dataquest post](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/pandas-big-data/) suggest a few memory optimizations.

Comment: It is two separate tick by tick trading data. Price and volume. I need to merge them by date. So, I will have three columns. Date, Stock A, Stock B.

Answer (score 3):

You can try using [`dask.dataframe`](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe.html#) to parallelize your task:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

# define lazy readers
aa = dd.read_csv('file1.csv')
bb = dd.read_csv('file2.csv')

# define merging logic
dd_merged = aa.merge(bb, on='column', how='outer')

# apply merge and convert to dataframe
df = dd_merged.compute()
```